# Combining 2 Files . 1 line to many lines

Tags: list-manipulation

2 Files A and B. A has 2593 lines and B has 18900000.
 I would like to Take A[i] and associate(added to the same line) it with 720 lines of B.
 Then A[1+1] associate it with the next 720 lines in B.
 So in the end A[2593] would be associated with the last 720 lines of file B.

I can do it with for loops, but would like a more elegant and effiecient way.

A={{1,2,3},{4,2,5},{9,11,3}...{5,2,8}}
 B= Same format

Any assistance or documentation would be appreciated.

Thank You
Michel

Comment: does `MapThread[Join, {A, Flatten /@ Partition[B, 720]}]` work?

Comment: is `Dimensions@B`  `{18900000,3}`?

Comment: That is not the form I am looking for,
The result would be as:
A[1]->B[1]
A[1]->B[2]
   .         .
   .         .
A[1]->B[720]
A[2]->B[721]
   .        .
   .        .
A[2]->B[1440]
A[3]->B[1441]
   .        .
   .        .
A[2593]->B[1866960] 

Thank You
Michel

Comment: how about `Join@@MapThread[Thread[Rule@##, List, {2}] &, {A, Partition[B, 720]}]`?

Comment: It is {1866960,6}
I am attempting to get it into a form for a neural Network.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
Join @@ MapThread[Thread[Rule @ ##, List, {2}] &, 
  {A, Partition[B[[;; 720 Length @ A]], 720]}]
```

Comment: I am getting this
MapThread::mptc: Incompatible dimensions of objects at positions {2, 1} and {2, 2} of MapThread[Thread[Rule[##1],List,{2}]&,{{{21,30,39,44,45,46},{5,12,16,19,45,48}},{{{1,5,20,24,28,52},{1,5,20,24,52,28},{1,5,20,28,24,52},{1,5,20,28,52,24},{1,5,20,52,24,28},{1,5,20,52,28,24},{1,5,24,20,28,52},<<37>>,{1,20,52,24,5,28},{1,20,52,24,28,5},{1,20,52,28,5,24},{1,20,52,28,24,5},{1,24,5,20,28,52},{1,24,5,20,52,28},<<670>>}}}]; dimensions are 2 and 1.

Comment: @MichelMesedahl, does `Join @@ MapThread[Thread[Rule @ ##, List, {2}] &, 
  {A, Partition[B[[;; 720 Length @ A]], 720]}]` work?

Comment: Hello,

This does work and it is very fast:

Join @@ MapThread[Thread[Rule @ ##, List, {2}] &, {A, Partition[B[[;; 720 Length @ A]], 720]}]

Thank You